# Why does updating Gradle break log4j imports?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, log4j2

I am attempting to update to Kotlin 1.4. In my build.gradle file, I have the following:

```
buildscript {
    allprojects {
        ext {
            kotlin_version = "1.3.70"
            ktor_version = "1.2.2"
            junit_version = "5.4.2"
            log4j_version = "2.11.2"
            jackson_version = "2.9.9"
            kafka_version = "2.3.0"
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://smartward.jfrog.io/smartward/gradle-dev'
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }
    }


    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.9.7"
    }
}
```

and later on:

```
        implementation(
        "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version",
        "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version",
        "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:$log4j_version",
        "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:$log4j_version",
        // For JSON mapping
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:$jackson_version",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:$jackson_version",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:$jackson_version",
        "com.natpryce:konfig:1.6.10.0",
        "org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:$kafka_version",
        
        "io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version",
        "io.ktor:ktor-locations:$ktor_version",
        "io.ktor:ktor-jackson:$ktor_version", 
        "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version",
        "io.ktor:ktor-client-apache:$ktor_version",
        "io.ktor:ktor-client-json:$ktor_version"
    )
```

My first step was to change kotlin_version to be "1.4.0". When running the build script, I was informed that Gradle needed to be updated as well. I did this, changing my gradle-wrapper.properties file (diff below):

```
-distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-all.zip
+distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.3-all.zip
```

This now means that some of my log4j imports no longer work. Namely:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator
```

I have attempted reverting to Kotlin 1.3.70, without reverting the Gradle update, and the issue persists, so I suspect a problem with Gradle, or my build script, but I'm not sure why or how to fix it. I have also attempted using Gradle 6.6, with the 4.17.1 version of org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle, but the problem persists.

Comment: Can you try with the latest lo4j package i.e. 2.13.3. Check this official documentation - https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html

Comment: Also the official documentation suggests to link to both `log4j-api` and `log4j-core`. Try this as well

Comment: @Sisir Adding log4j-core is what worked (which surprised me, since slf4j includes core). Please make this an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [official documentation of Log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html) you need to link to both `log4j-api` and `log4j-core` to consume the package properly.

Answer (score 3):

## Use `dependencyInsight` to see what's going wrong

It sounds like what's happening is that the version of log4j that ends up being used isn't the version you were expecting.

Dependency version resolution can get pretty complicated, especially when you have lots of dependencies. Different things want different versions of the same dependency, but Gradle has to pick one version that will end up on the classpath. In general, it will pick the newest version from among all the versions that have been requested.

There are two reasons I can think of that upgrading Gradle might have changed the version of log4j that ends up being used:

- Something in Gradle itself could be adding a dependency on log4j, and might now be requesting a newer version than was used in the older Gradle distribution.
- On the other hand, it's possible that the way version conflicts are resolved has actually subtly changed in the newer version of Gradle.

Luckily, Gradle gives you some tools to help figure out what's going on. I would suggest comparing the output of the following command *both before and after* updating the Gradle version.

```sh
gradle dependencyInsight --dependency log4j
```

This will print out a tree-like report of everything that's using log4j, and will tell you why a particular version was selected. It might take some time to understand the report, especially if it's long, but it's worth reading through it carefully.

## Use `platform` constraints to force the correct version

Projects like log4j are made up of several artifacts (`log4j-api`, `log4j-core`, etc). The process of resolving the various transitive dependency versions in your build can end up introducing versions that don't match each other. It's important to make sure that all the artifacts have matching versions.

To help solve this, log4j provides an additional 'bill of materials' artifact, `log4j-bom`. BOM artifacts don't contain any code, but they specify a list of dependencies, along with the versions that should be used.

Since version 5, [Gradle lets you use BOM files](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:bom_import) to suggest or enforce versions for a set of dependencies. Applying a 'platform' dependency of this sort doesn't add or remove any actual dependencies to your build, but it does influence or control the versions of the dependencies you already have.

In your case, you could add the following to your dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation enforcedPlatform("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-bom:$log4j_version")
}
```

This adds the `log4j-bom` as an `enforcedPlatform` dependency, *guaranteeing* that *every* log4j dependency used in your application will always have the version you specify. This is a powerful tool and should help make sure you don't run into problems like this in future.

Comment: This is an excellently written answer! Unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem. @Sisir's comments on the question were the fix - to include an explicit dependency on log4j-core.